# Elevator operator tells scary stories, ends up trapped in the mirror

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie or TV anthology series.

I believe the movie may have come out in the late 1980s to 1999. I watched it with Turkish dubbing and in colour. Possibly American movie.

- An elevator in a building starts with a few passengers.
- The elevator stopped working.
- Old man (elevator operator) started telling scary stories.
- He is telling three different stories. (In his stories, we are watching the film. I don't remember the stories.)

**At the end of the movie**

- Elevator starts to work again and the passengers are going.
- We see the elevator operator trapped in the mirror and he cries for help.
- Maybe a witch cursed the old man.

The old man was played by a black actor. A little chubby with white hair.

I thought it might be *"The Twilight Zone"*, but it was not. 
I watched as a kid, I don't remember much.

Comment: you might wanna narrow down this year range 1986 to 1999

Comment: I narrowed it down 1980 to 1996.

Comment: By the things you are saying it must be a horror, is that right?

Comment: Yes that right. Like "The Twilight Zone".

Comment: I asked you to short the year range. 16 years is a big gap.

Comment: Ok. I thought some more.     I watched it in 1992 to 1997.
 Release date may 1980s to 1996.

Comment: The "Vault of Horror" has five guys in an elevator, but no operator or mirror, also 1972. But interesting to note the elevator ride as a "bumper" between stories.

Comment: do you remember the run time of the movie? If you know the length of the movie add here

Comment: I don't remember. But it should be more than 30 minutes.
Because there are different stories within the film.

Comment: i looked all anthology movies released in these years but none of them contains plot details you described.

Comment: @pori Narrow down: 1980 to 1992.

Comment: That question title would make a curious newspaper title

Comment: Well, I feel it must be a TV episode. Are you sure it is a movie?

Comment: @Rippy I am not sure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Could this be the German TV movie "[Geisterstunde - Fahrstuhl ins Jenseits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119182/?ref_=nv_sr_2)" from **1997**?

[Rolf Hoppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolf_Hoppe) was the elevator operator, he is white haired, but he is not black. (He is wearing a black tuxedo, that might have mislead your memory?)

Here is the plot summary from an IMDb-user:

> A night watchman tells **three extraordinary stories** to a journalist and a producer, **trapped with him in a lift**. Embedded in a single story, **three tales** develop some interesting themes, notably that of a double persecutor. Some good actors for some harrowing moments.

(highlights by me)

[Here](http://www.tvtoday.de/entertainment/kino/geisterstunde-fahrstuhl-ins-jenseits_1324598.html) are some pictures from that movie, they might ring a bell.

I only remember the old man, but what I've read on some German pages, the 3 stories are about:

1. A 17 year old girl meets another girl while sleepwalking. Later it turns out that this other girl lived in the same house, but was killed 33 years ago.
2. A female painter moves into a new flat and hears a man tyrannising his family.
3. An unsuccessful comic-strip artist, who creates a successful twin using a **magical mirror**.

Comment: Yes that's the movie!  Some of my details were wrong (The actor is not black).  But i definitely remember a sleepwalking girl and her father. 
https://www.prisma.de/filme/Geisterstunde-Fahrstuhl-ins-Jenseits,360383

 Thank you so much. You are the best! <3

Comment: @pori Glad I could help :)

Comment: @madmada Thank you very much for setting up a bounty again!

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).